# grails spring-security-core how to access scaffolded pages

Tags: grails, spring-security

When you install the security plugin via this turorial: http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

By default it locks out everything.  You cant access any page.  This is fine, as you can add this annotation to each controller method:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def myView() {
```

However, if you use:

```
      static scaffold = true
```

1. How would I create default role of say admin for all pages, so that I don't lock out pages from any access by default?
2. How do you add roles to scaffolded pages?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spring security plugin for Grails offers several ways of securing pages/actions/controllers. Annotations is just one way. Typically annotations are used when you have generated controllers and not scaffolded controllers. Usually you will secure your application using simple map if you rely upon scaffolding.

The various ways of securing resources are outlined in [the documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/requestMappings.html).

If you use the simple map then you can easily define a global pattern that will allow all ADMIN roles to access everything. Keep in mind the first matching pattern is the one that applies. So for example:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   '/**':                ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
   '/':                  ['permitAll'],
   '/index':             ['permitAll'],
   '/index.gsp':         ['permitAll'],
   '/**/js/**':          ['permitAll'],
   '/**/css/**':         ['permitAll'],
   '/**/images/**':      ['permitAll'],
   '/**/favicon.ico':    ['permitAll'],
   '/login/**':          ['permitAll'],
   '/logout/**':         ['permitAll']
]
```

In addition, reading the documentation for this plugin will help answer a lot of potential questions about it's use and how to configure it exactly the way you need it. It's well written and very worth the time it takes.

Comment: '/**':                ['ROLE_ADMIN'] did the trick. I saw this in the manaual but assumed that this would mean that everything has role ADMIN, as I could not find in the manual how it resuolves conflicts (e.g. if you say ROLE_USER in the controller, but ADMIN in the interceptURLMap).

Comment: Also, the manual page says that this should be viewable by anyone:  "def anybody() {
      render 'anyone can see this'
   }" but this is not the case, out of the box, everything is hidden from every user.

Comment: Anyother stupid question I cant find in any example, how do you logout?

Comment: visiting /logout will do logout. <g:link controller="logout">Click here to logout</g:link> in your GSP.

Comment: Wow, that worked!  So easy when you know.  You saved me hours.  One last question, is there an easy way to setup controllers and view to edit users and roles, or do I have to create these by hand?

Comment: Take a look at the spring-security-ui plugin or read up in the documentation link I sent you on using a database to map your roles.